# Running Anaconda Python Examples

Tags: python, anaconda

I'd like to run any example .py script that uses matplotlib or pyqtgraph to see how it looks.

The problem is, none of the examples included with the Anaconda3-2.0.1-Windows-x86 install work.   For example, I open Spyder3.4 that was installed with Anaconda, but when I open/run any of the .py files ( C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib) nothing happens... No error message, nothing in the output tab.

I've installed this on a WinXp virtual machine that also has Qt5 creator/designer and PyQt installed.  Is there any known conflict or path issues having PyQt installed alongside Anaconda?

How can I tell if Anaconda and its packages (namely pyqtgraph, matplotlib and pyqt) installed correctly?

Comment: activate your environment (if you created one) and type `python -c "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)"`. If you see something, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't run the files in site-packages directly to use the modules. You should start a Python console in Spyder or the IPython notebook and use `import matplotlib` to access matplotlib.